# Spring Data Neo4j inconsistent responses

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

Is the following normal with SDN?

.../api/friendships/2 returns following so I do have a friendship there with the id 2:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/friendships/2"
    },
    "requester" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/friendships/2/requester"
    },
    "confirmer" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/friendships/2/confirmer"
    }
  }
}
```

But .../api/friendships returns following so it does not show this friendship with id 2:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/friendships{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: `friendships` has no relationships so it wouldn't make sense to have a `requester` link, if you mean that.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. Otherwise, a friendship is a relationship entity with two nested resources on it as in it connects two users together; one is the requester and the other is the confirmer. As in one makes the friend request and the other one confirms.

Comment: So that's not what I mean at all. I mean I can retrieve a single friendship namely the one with id 2. But the friendships collection is empty.

Comment: As in when I retrieve the collection there appears to be nothing in it while there is actually one resource.